# Weird `LOOKUP` behaviour in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was playing around in a sheet when I stumbled upon (to me) unexpected behaviour. I isolated the behaviour an put it in a different sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UWCNml2hvIp3zQbfI8NJovyf37C44cxacqJIChR2BUE/edit?usp=sharing

I have a bunch of codes to which I assigned times (Column A and B), this is the data source. Then I want to use this data to lookup the times based on a code. For this I use `LOOKUP` but it doesn't seem return the right value every time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've linked to a live working sheet which reproduces the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOOKUP` is meant for sorted data, use `VLOOKUP` or `HLOOKUP` instead.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570#Notes?hl=en see "Notes"